# Show Errors instead of Internal Server Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

When my code have error (even syntax errors) browser show `500 - Internal Server Error`,
In `.env` I set the `APP_DEBUG` to `true` and `APP_LOG_LEVEL` is `debug`

How can I enable error messages?

**UPDATE:**

I use Laravel 5.3

**UPDATE 2:**

I use Apache and defined `VirtualHost` to access this app :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemail@domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/Dev/Web/site/public"
    ServerName site.local
    ServerAlias www.site.local
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/site.local-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/site.local-access_log" common

    <Directory "/Dev/Web/site/public/">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**UPDATE 3:**

My `/etc/hosts` records:

```
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost gat.local www.gat.local site.local www.site.local shop.local www.shop.local
```

Comment: are you running laravel by `php artisan serve` ?

Comment: @Rishi No, I defined `VirtualHost` in my apache

Comment: is laravel is running fine by `php artisan serve` ? If yes then provide details  that what you did to make virtual host ?

Comment: In production environment you should consider watching logs and errors in respective directories.

Comment: @Rishi When I use `php artisan serve` server will run but my browser cannot load `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: @AlokPatel I'm in developing, How can I set to development mode ?

Comment: Check your log file..

Comment: If it is absolute new installation then it should work, I am sure you have some wrong code written somewhere in your project.

Comment: @Rishi I updated my question

Comment: please add both vhost and host file  detail.

Comment: @Rishi Yes, it's fresh install, for example in routes I called a method which not exists : `Route::post('/', 'AccountController@checkEmails');` , my method name is `checkEmail` , but I get `500 Internal Server Error` instead of reason of problem

Comment: @Rishi Question updated with my `/etc/hosts` content

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After many tries, I found problem,

Everything return to file permissions,

I changed the permission of `laravel.log` in `storage/logs` to `777` and everything work fine !

Comment: I stated this in my answer and also set it to 774 not 777.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer **you can't**. Why?

Simply because **500 - Internal Server Error** is exactly what it says Internal Server Error, it has nothing to do with Laravel. Server software (Apache in your case) causes error 500. Most likely **permissions problem**. (server software can not read / write to certain files etc.)

From Laravel documentation:

> After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run.

You have to check Apache logs

Default on OSX machine `/private/var/log/apache2`

---

You want to see more errors? Follow up this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php).

---

Neat trick, make sure to have one entry per project in your hosts file.

```
#127.0.0.1 project1.dev www.project1.dev
#127.0.0.1 project2.dev www.project2.dev
.
.
.
```

Why? You can just comment out / delete line, searchable, easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Yes you right, but it's very strange because for syntax errors (for example missing semicolons) I am still Internal Server error !

Comment: @MajAfy read contents of provided link to another SO thread, that may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

@MajAfy You can use `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar`. This will give you in depth knowledge of every error. What query you are running and lot more.

Here is the link https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar .

Its easy to install due to its well documentation.

Comment: Thanks but I need simple error for some syntax errors, I don't know why laravel does not show these errors!